# Confusion about google ima tags (resolution)

Tags: adsense, google-dfp, google-ad-manager, google-ima, google-advertising-id

There is so many places where you can specify the width & height of the a google ima ad tag:

1-`https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&` (**sz:** inside the tag parameter)

2-`new google.ima.AdDisplayContainer(div_id)` **div_id** has a fixed width & height (html5 ima sdk with js)

3-`googletag.defineSlot("/" + scope.vgNetwork + "/" + scope.vgUnitPath, size, div_id)` **size** could be an array of sizes like: **[[300,100], [468, 70]]**

4-`adsManager.init(width, height, google.ima.ViewMode.NORMAL);` here is the adsmanager parameters

5-`adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotWidth = 748;
adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotHeight = 90
adsRequest.linearAdSlotWidth= 468
adsRequest.linearAdSlotHeight= 70` here we have 4 spots, two for non linear **linearAdSlotWidth** **nonLinearAdSlotHeight**  & two of linear **linearAdSlotWidth** **linearAdSlotHeight**

the problem that I'm facing right now is that most of the time ads are not displayed, I get two kind of errors:

```
1-The VAST response document is empty.

2-Non linear assets were found in the VAST ad response, but none of them matched the video player's capabilities.
```

Testing my tags width google ima vast inspector goes OK, ads are displayed 100%, so I guess it has something to do width my setup, specially the width & height configuration, is it possible if someone can help & make a relation between all these width & height configurations, and which is important and making the difference.

Comment: What is your ad tag, and which IMA SDK platform are you using? I don't think those two errors have anything to do with sizes of your ads.

Comment: Hi @chauduyphanvu I reported this issue to google repo so they can check the tags, here is an example: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=********4&slotname=2992119445/8478941125&ad_type=skippablevideo_image_flash&description_url=xxxxx&videoad_start_delay=0. These tags come from google ad exchange, most of them are banners and fullslots, banners are not working in mobile devices(vertical position) => horizental position is working, so my guess here is that the width is important for banners because they come from google dfp or adsense in a specific min-width

Comment: Yes, I understand, but again I don't see a connection between sizes and receiving those errors on your end.  If you open a ticket here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ima-sdk) with additional details and replication steps, the team can investigate.

Comment: Ok, here is a simple example, imagine google adx send us a set of banners(720px, 520px, 480px) as a result of one single tag, our player has to choose one of these banners based on best resolution fit. So if the user has a small screen, say 360px, it would be impossible to show the banner full at 100%, a part of it will be hidden. This is against adsense regulations, so that's why ima block it right a way: Non linear assets were found in the VAST ad response, but none of them matched the video player's.... The second error is something related to visitors types, we reported to google repo too